# Direct Update in MFP8 not working even deploy latest web resources

Tags: android, angular, ibm-mobilefirst, mfp, direct-update

Good day,

I am currently developing an android mobile app in my local, with `mfp8` server.

I can launch the app in my android phone, and successful fire a call to the `mfp` server.

I try to edit something on an HTML file in the angular project (mobile app front end). I run some command to deploy the web resource to mfp server:

```
npm run android
mfpdev app register
mfpdev app webupdate
```

From the mfp console, I can see that the application and web resources last updated date is matched with the time I run those command.

I am expected after I stop and run the app in my mobile, the app will be able to detect something changes and prompt for update. However, it didn't happen, and my app still nothing changes.

Anyone know what mistake on this? Changes in HTML file should be a correct way to test the direct update right?

Edit **
I just found that in MFP log, there is a line as follow:

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID ibs_mobile. An invalid user ID or password was specified.
```

However, I am still able to log in to my app. I am not sure of is this related to my direct update or not.

Comment: Is it ionic app ?

Comment: @VittalPai,  am not sure how to differentiate on it, but I didnt see any ionic command. I am using Cordova.

Comment: The audit message in the logs is irrelevant. That has no bearing on this. Check if there are any messages in the server logs to the effect : "native checksum... does not match.."

Comment: You can follow docs here https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/direct-update/  incase you are doing something incorrect

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `cordova` command to prepare the app instead of `npm run`

Try the following steps

a.  `cordova prepare android`

b.  `mfpdev app webupdate`

Comment: Hi Srik, its still same. By right, my app should be able to detect the updated version once I tab on my app to open it, correct? Just ask to confirm that I did is correct. I am new to Mobile app and MFP.

Comment: Hi @Srik, I just found something in my log file and updated my question.